# Imacro - Error -921 with a field-wrapper

Tags: php, html, firefox, imacros

I m recording an imacro macro.

Here is my script:

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=EM ATTR=TXT:Lui<SP>écrire
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:postform ATTR=ID:subj CONTENT=Hello
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:postform ATTR=ID:text CONTENT=Bonjour
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:postform ATTR=ID:inclure CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:postform ATTR=*
```

Here is the code in the body of the page:

```
<div id="form-subj" class="rc-form-field ">
<label for="subj">Sujet :</label>
<span class="field-wrapper">
<input id="subj" type="text" value="" name="subj" maxlength="40">
</span>
</div>
```

I attached a capture too of the page.

I suppose that the field-wrapper is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The attachment of the Page HTML is not complete.

Please revise.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late answer.

Here is the page html

```
    <div id="content">
<div id="ctn-iframe">
<p id="load-iframe" style="display: none;">
<img src="/static/img/loader.gif?v2.2"/>
</p>
<iframe data-src="http://legacy.reseaucontact.com/bp/?action=post&ruid=3923690" frameborder="0" id="iframe-legacy" name="iframeLegacy" width="100%" scrolling="no" onload="window.parent.scroll(0,0);" src="http://legacy.reseaucontact.com/bp/?action=post&ruid=3923690" style="display: inline-block; height: 623px;"/>
</div>
</div>
<div id="aside">
<div class="inner">
<section id="search-container">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bundles/applicationrc/js/plugin/jquery-ui.js?v2.2"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
<section id="widget-community-stats">
<section id="widget-selection-mois" class="widget autopromo">
<div>
<h3 class="footer-title">
<div class="clearfix">
<p>Vous voulez plus de visites sur votre fiche? Envoyez-nous votre photo pour être membre-vedette!</p>
<a href="/profil/selection-mois" class="rc-btn">Soumettre ma photo</a>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
</section>
</div>
</div>
<div id="main-footer">
<div class="inner-shadow" style="display: block;" id="inner-shadow-1"/>
<div class="inner-shadow" style="display: block;" id="inner-shadow-2"/>
<div class="inner-shadow" style="display: block;" id="inner-shadow-3"/>
</div>
</div>
```